# I am trying to grab the index of the row and I do row[0] which is the actual value in a sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to debug a specific row in a Google Spreadsheet and use the `row[0]` in a filtered table but I want to see the actual row in the sheet.

What I am getting is the email address, which is correct, but what do I have to do to see the actual row number? Is there a way to expose to actual row number my information?

I want to get access might skip a couple of rows then want to work on that row then skip a couple more rows and work on another row.

Is there a way to expose to row like row 6 and row 9 lets say, I have looked in the log and when I use `row[0]` I get the actual data, but I want instead row 6 or row 9?

I am using this:

```
Logger.log('ROW row is :' + row[0]);  // The email is what i do not want !
```

Comment: There are many ways to retrieve the row number. The most suitable in your case depends on the rest of your code. Can you provide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be more specific with the question and provide some example data. Also, use comma and periods and new-lines, as they help to group thoughts.

To my understanding, you want to iterate (go) through each row in a particular Spreadsheet. You want to filter out certain row, but it is not stated what the criteria is, therefore I will make a assumption.

Assumptions: You want to iterate through certain rows.

```
// enter here the rows you want to filter in, ie use
const useTheseRowsOnly = [1, 3, 4];

// lets get all the data in the active Sheet (or whichever Sheet)
const sheetDataAsArr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

// now lets go through each row
sheetDataAsArr.forEach( (rowArr, index) => {
  const rowNumber = index + 1; // index starts at 0, but rows start at 1

  // skip unwanted rows
  if( useTheseRowsOnly.indexOf(rowNumber) == -1 ){
    return
  }
  // here we work with the rows like this
  const columnAValue = rowArr[0];
  const columnBValue = rowArr[1] ;
  Logger.log("Row: " + rowNumber + " has in Column A: " + columnAValue)
})
```

Comment: you do not need to use `.getRange()` because `.getDataRange()` already gets all the data on the particular sheet. If you need a particular range, then approach it by setting a `var startRow = 2` and then `.getRange( startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn)`

Comment: if it answered your question, then please add the checkmark so other's can see that your issue is resolved.

Comment: I resolved the problem and posted the answer above but do not see how to add the check mark to this system !